# Taxonomy: Sort Order for Nodes Under Multiple Lists

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, views

I am creating a restaurant menu vocabulary that contains terms and sub-terms. Menu Items (nodes) may be listed under more than one item.

For example Cobb Salad is listed under:

Appetizers >> Salads
Healthy Stuff >> Meals Under 600 Calories

I've tried using the weight module but this isn't effective since it only sets one sort order globally. I need to be able to set the sort order for nodes under each taxonomy term knowing that each node can be associated with multiple terms.

For example, that Cobb Salad might be the top choice under Salads, but the fifth choice under Meals Under 600 Calories.

Any good solutions or combinations of modules that can do this and also allow the site user to easily maintain the menus going forward?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I would like to know this too, seems like it would be a common problem yet the sorting plugins I've seen have only thought that you might want to sort by one criteria